# opencv contour for lines

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a black and white image made up of lines, like the following:[image]

I am trying to get the points that can describe the curve, so essentially the contour. However, contours trace the boundary, and so in the case of lines, it traces from start to end, and then back to start.

I am getting the contour as follows:
`cv::findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);`

To try and get rid of points that are represented by backtracking i am running

`approxPolyDP(contour, contour, epsilon, true);` However this still leaves points on the way back.

Is there a better way of solving this problem? My line drawings can be more complicated that this one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this issue is that you are using the `cv::RETR_TREE` as **contour retrieval mode**. This mode as the [documentations](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) says:

> **CV_RETR_TREE** retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full
>   hierarchy of nested contours.

So in your line you are finding inner and outer line of the main line. In this case it can be the solution to use (for only the outer line) **CV_RETR_EXTERNAL** instead of **CV_RETR_TREE**.

> **CV_RETR_EXTERNAL** retrieves only the extreme outer contours.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason even if you have a very thin contour, CV_RETR_TREE will not count as 1 it will count as 2. You can  experience it by trying.

Comment: Try to change also CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE with  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE and tell me the result please

Comment: It may be better to share whole code then because according to my experiences it should work.